# Is there a such thing as 'rested' in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Similar to WoW, if you go to a tavern or inn, you can gain a state of being rested that doubles your XP for a period of time.  Does this or something similar exist in Diablo 3?

Or is there any benefit from exiting the game in an Inn or *safe* location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The heros of Sanctuary never rest. They must destroy the evil.

So no - D3 does not have a "rested" bonus.